# need to find a dynamic wss url from a site

Tags: go, websocket, wss, ws

this is hard to explain,  because is prob very simple for someone who knows this well, and the language barrier can make it more difficult sorry.

ok so I am writing a bot for mozilla hubs. and I can go into "developer tools" on my browser and on the "wss" network options I can see the wss address and have my bot connect to that..

the issue.

This changes and is always diff as the main site.. so is I cant just use the GO gorilla libs to update from https to wss because i do not know the URL.
This has to be possible because the browser does it!

so all the wss examples I see is someone making a websocket example on the "same" url as in
to get to mywebsockets.site just do the handshake so it upgrades from http to wss but this is a diff url.. how do I find out this url when I do a get request from my browser or my bot, or any libs..

another example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)


func main() {
    c, _ , err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial("wss://hubs.mozilla.com/zWXKxxxx/", nil)
    //c, _ , err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial("wss://hubs.mozilla.com", nil)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    // do something with c, a *websocket.Conn

    fmt.Println(c)
}
```

this both will give error on the handshake and the reason is because is not that URL
but the browser can get the right one always.
usually they are like:

```
//webSocketSite := "brave-elf.reticulum.io/socket/websocket?vsn=2.0.0"
    //webSocketSite := "peaceful-warlock.reticulum.io/socket/websocket?vsn=2.0.0"
    //webSocketSite := "goofy-druid.reticulum.io/socket/websocket?vsn=2.0.0"
    //webSocketSite := "mystifying-artificer.reticulum.io/socket/websocket?vsn=2.0.0"
    //webSocketSite := "epic-bard.reticulum.io/socket/websocket?vsn=2.0.0"
    //webSocketSite := "zealous-ranger.reticulum.io/socket/websocket?vsn=2.0.0"
    //webSocketSite := "wonderful-psion.reticulum.io/socket/websocket?vsn=2.0.0"
    //webSocketSite := "loving-bard.reticulum.io/socket/websocket?vsn=2.0.0"
    //webSocketSite := "wss://stoic-giant.reticulum.io/socket/websocket?vsn=2.0.0"
    //webSocketSite := "wss://nifty-rogue.reticulum.io/socket/websocket?vsn=2.0.0"
    webSocketSite := "wss://happy-orc.reticulum.io/socket/websocket?vsn=2.0.0"
```

This keeps changing so I need to maually open my dev tools on my browser and add it..
Im trying to avoid doing this manually.
if the browser can do it.. there has to be a way.

sorry if this is to confusing or to simple. I honestly cant find an example for this since all WSS examples "assume" you are always upgrading to the same URL

Comment: Inspect the Javascript code to determine how the application discovers the URL.  Do the same thing from your Go code.

Comment: the wss:// url indicates the address of one such room, right? and you are trying to connect to that room from your go code?